# Capture Send with Input

Tags: autohotkey

I have a script that I use to insert special characters and implement dead keys. The special characters are inserted with `SendEvent`. When a dead key is activated, the script runs `Input, key, L1` and looks up the result in a table to find a composed character.

This works fine for real keypresses, but if I trigger a dead key and then cause a special character to be inserted with `SendEvent`, the `Input` call doesn't notice it. The special character is inserted verbatim and the next real keypress will go to the `Input` call.

How can I alter my script so that special characters inserted by the script will be captured by `Input`?

I am running a minimal script to demonstrate the issue:

```
SpecialCharacter(char) {
    SendEvent %char%
}

DeadKey(combining) {
    Input, key, L1

    SendEvent %key%
    SendEvent %combining%
}

^q::SpecialCharacter("a")
^w::DeadKey("b")

^ESC::Reload
```

The actual application will be more complex.

Actual output:

- <kbd>Ctrl-q</kbd>: `a`
- <kbd>Ctrl-w</kbd>, <kbd>x</kbd>: `xb`
- <kbd>Ctrl-w</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl-q</kbd>: no output
- <kbd>Ctrl-w</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl-q</kbd>, <kbd>x</kbd>: `xb`

Desired output:

- <kbd>Ctrl-w</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl-q</kbd>: `ab`
- <kbd>Ctrl-w</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl-q</kbd>, <kbd>x</kbd>: `abx`

I tried fiddling around with `SendLevel`/`#InputLevel`, but I don't think that those affect the behavior of the `Input` command.

Comment: Show some code. It will help greatly.

Comment: If you want to use dead keys, you probably have to switch to the US keyboards instead of the US International keyboard. This is what I did to work with dead keys. see: http://superuser.com/questions/677727/windows-8-add-german-umlauts-to-us-keyboard-layout-maybe-using-autohotkey/784982?noredirect=1#comment1087201_784982

Comment: I've edited the question. The example code is what I am actually running at the moment.